# Is it possible to use a SQL query as a result in CASE in ORACLE SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, case

For example something like this:

```
SELECT CASE
   WHEN COL_1 LIKE '%4'
   THEN (SELECT MAX(COL_1) FROM TAB_1)
   ELSE MAX(COL_1)
   END AS "RESULT"
FROM TAB_1
```

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  The answer to your question is emphatically "yes", but your query is malformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is fine.  A query in this context is called a *scalar* subquery.  It needs to return one column (in general) and at most one row.

This particular version, though, has problems:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COL_1 LIKE '%4'
             THEN (SELECT MAX(COL_1) FROM TAB_1)
             ELSE MAX(COL_1)
        END) AS "RESULT"
FROM TAB_1
```

In particular, for the `CASE WHEN` to work, then `COL_1` needs to be in the `GROUP BY`.  However, it would be strange to then be taking the maximum.

I suspect you intend two columns or two rows:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN COL_1 LIKE '%4' THEN COL_1 END) as MAX_4 
       MAX(CASE WHEN COL_1 LIKE '%4' THEN NULL ELSE COL_1 END) as MAX_not4 
FROM Ttabl_1
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Mistakenly I typed a wrong scenario up there. Query should look like this:


SELECT (CASE WHEN COL_1 LIKE '%4'
             THEN (SELECT MAX(COL_1) FROM TAB_1 where COL like '%4')
             ELSE MAX(COL_1)
        END) AS "RESULT"
FROM TAB_1

So what I am trying to get is that if there are some values that ends in 4, query should fetch the highest value ending with 4. Else it should just return the highest value from COL_1. And the result should be just one value or one row.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do that, here is an example for that

Lets assume following 2 tables

Table 1: CITY (ID, NAME, COUNTRYCODE)

Table 2: COUNTRY (CODE, NAME, CONTINENT, REGION)

For the above tables you can use the query as

```
    select id,
           case when countrycode like 'AUS'
           then (select name from country where code like 'AUS')
           else countrycode end
    from city;
```

Comment: Thanks Kunal, but in my case I am using an aggregate function because of which its throwing an error - Not a group by function, just like Gordon pointed. Any ideas on fixing it? I tried to add a group by clause at the end of subquery in THEN part as well.

Comment: Looking at what you want to achieve you can do something like this:

with  max_value as (select max(col_1) from tab_1)
select case when col_1 like '%4'
           then (select max(col_1) from tab_1 where col_1 like '%4')
           else (select * from max_value) end
    from tab_1;

Or you can assign (select max(col_1) from tab_1) to a variable and use it.

Comment: No success. Even with WITH clause, its still throwing the same error - Not a group by expression.

Comment: Can you please post the exact query and the error please ?